# Kernel Function to Add BlendMode of Texture

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am passing two textures to Kernel Functions as below

```
kernel void compute(texture2d<float,access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    texture2d<float, access::read> src [[texture(1)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
```

I need to blend the src texture to output texture with different Blendmodes. Cannot we do it with two texture passing. I think we can do it by passing two texture for reading and one texture for writing but I think It is not the best option. Suggest a way to do Kernel Function Add blendmode with Two Texture passing

Comment: Have you tried qualifying your output texture with `access::read_write`? As of Metal 1.2, kernel and graphics functions can read and write the same texture.

Comment: Is multi sample supports read write ?

Comment: I don't think so. What's the use case for running a compute kernel on a multisample texture? Are you doing a custom MSAA resolve?